# Matrix field freezes on localhost when I try to make a new entry

Tags: entry

I have a simple Matrix field that includes two sub-fields: a one line plain text field, and a multi-line plain text field. When I try to create an entry Craft freezes at the Create New Entry screen. **When I run the same Craft configuration on a remote apache server no freezing occurs**. I'm using a wamp server (on a PC of course). I have the same problem on my wamp-craft setup on PC at work and my PC at home. I've never had a problem with any wamp server before and have never had a problem with Craft. My guess is it's a wamp permissions problem that's specific to the Matrix field (this is my first attempt at using the Matrix field feature). Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say freeze, does it ever resolve? Do you get any errors in your browser's console or in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` or in your WAMP/Apache error logs?

Comment: It never resolves. It hangs on the screen title Create New Entry and there's the Save button in the upper right corner, my top level menu options on the left side of the screen, but nothing else renders on the page. Where the entry fields are supposed to be it's blank. By the way, the left side menu options still function. I have two instances of Craft running on the localhost. One of them has Dev Mode enabled and the other does not. Both exhibit the problem but neither instance throws errors. And as a reminder, my remote server install works just fine.

Comment: Brad, I see no browser console log errors either. It's baffling!

Comment: I've thought of some further ways I can try to isolate this problem. I'll remove matrix block fields one by one, and then matrix blocks one by one and see what happens with each change. I'll report what I find in case anyone else has had this issue (it might take a day or two to get to it).

Comment: I got back to it quicker than I thought. As explained above, I had two sub-fields in one Matrix block defined. I deleted one of those sub-fields and tested. Same problem. I deleted the other and tested, leaving me with one matrix block defined with no sub-fields. Same problem. I deleted the block. Same problem. Only when I changed the field type from Matrix to Plain Text did it work again. The problem is definitely related to the Matrix field. Once again, as a reminder, the problem only happens on my wamp-based localhost machines. My remote site with matrix fields works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I also should mention that I'm using the latest Craft build both locally and remotely.

Comment: Well, you're doing better than me... can't even get WAMP to install on my Win10 box. You running the latest version of it (3.0.6)?

Comment: Looks like I need to update my wamp server installs. The install file I used about four months ago is titled this: 
"wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b"

But, then again, if the latest won't install for you...hmm.

Comment: Brad, by the way, my wamp servers are both running on Win10 machines.

Comment: Could just be my box, too. I'd try updating to the latest if you can. Maybe checkout XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or MAMP (https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/), too.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by upgrading my wampserver from ver 2.5 to 3.03.